# Python module mysql-connector does not see new changes

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb, mysql-connector

I use the `mysql.connector` module to fetch rows in a python script but when I update a table using the terminal, my script doesen't see any changes.

My code is this:

```
import mysql.connector

database = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='password', database='my_db')
cursor = database.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM my_table')
print(cursor.fetchall())

cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM my_table')
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

The first time it always reads the correct values but at the second time it does not see changes even when I have update my database.

I tried this solutions but it still did not work:

- I tried updating the database using the `mysql.connector` module
- I tried installing some older versions
- I tried using the root user

Answer (score 1):

When use performs `DML` like `update`, delete, etc You have to commit cursor after performing the operation otherwise your operation not save. There are use case of commit cursor some time

- due to the electricity issue
- atomicity transaction will rollback or commit latter

like

```
import mysql.connector

database = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='password', database='my_db')
cursor = database.cursor()

try:  
    cursor.execute("update Employee set name = 'alex' where id = 110")  
    cursor.commit()  
except:  
    cursor.rollback()  
  
cursor.close()
```

commit if the update will succeed otherwise rollback if got any error at the database level

or you can pass `autocommit=True` when you connect with database it will work too it's global configuration it will commit of some interval of time
like

```
database = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='password', database='my_db', autocommit=True)
cursor = database.cursor()
```

Comment: please mark the answer as right so it will good to use for people in future.